# raster2pgsql: queries on imported raster are NULL

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I loaded a tif-file of some soil data into postgres with:

```
raster2pgsql -c -I -F -C -r -M -s 31467 -t 200x200 soil_file.tif gis.soil_map | psql -U user -d database -h localhost -p 5432
```

which worked perfectly fine. The tif itself shows data when imported in QGIS and also the the imported raster from my database shows its values in QGIS.

**Here my problem:**
But when I want to query my raster within my database the query is always empty:

```
SELECT rid, (ST_SummaryStats(rast, 1)).*  from gis.soil_map
```

[image]

and I have absolutely no idea what could cause this. The same procedure work fine with a different raster from a different source, so I think this might have to do with the file, but as I said, no idea what to look for.

Comment: How many bands does your data have? Because the form of the function you have used suggests you are only interested in band 1. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, they all have one band, they are no satellite images or something, but statical values in raster form. At the moment I think, that Postgres cannot handle the float64 files properly, so I try to save them with less precision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, so the problem was, that the file was of type float64 and Postgres can't handle this (or at least my server). After I converted the image to float32, Summary stats and everthing can be computed.

I used GDAL.translate as it is implented in QGIS.

Cheers!